# Enter a Schengen country with Romanian resident permit?

Tags: resident-permit, schengen, romanian-citizens

i'm Romanian citizen and married with Indonesian citizen. we are planning to move in Holland. my question is, does my wife need to apply visa to entry in Holland? she has Romanian resident permit. i want to move together directly with her.

Comment: According to https://ind.nl/en/residence-permits/family-and-partner/apply-for-verification-against-eu-law-for-a-family-member-of-a-citizen-of-the-union as a visa national your wife needs a *facilitation visa*, which she can apply for in Romania

Comment: Does your wife's card say that it is a residence card for a family member of an EU citizen?